# I have recently converted my project to maven. But have an error Resource read error: Could not load com/sun/xml/txw2/Content.class

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I have recently converted my project to maven. I have added all .jar files for META-INF/lib to maven dependencies. but the error is Resource read error: Could not load com/sun/xml/txw2/Content.class.I also have explicitly added few repositories to .m/repositories...

```
SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load com/sun/xml/txw2/Content.class.
    java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3512)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1458)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1686)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2262)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2168)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2120)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1942)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1927)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4138)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Oct 13, 2016 5:31:04 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase findResourceInternal
    SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load com/sun/xml/txw2/DatatypeWriter.class.
    java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3512)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1458)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1686)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2265)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2168)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2120)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1942)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1927)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4138)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and the pom.xml file is like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stephenc.simple-java-mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>sun.misc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sun.misc.BASE64Decoder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.txw2</groupId>
    <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
    <version>20070616</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>
</project>
```

also the .m2 repository folder format is:

```
C:\Users\userName\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\txw2
|_txw2
  |_20070616 ->_remote.repositories,txw2-20070616,txw2-20070616.jar.sha1,txw2-       20070616.pom,txw2-20070616.pom.sha1
|_txw2-project
```

Comment: Seems like a class format error, maybe because of a corrupted jar. Have you successfully opened the tw2 jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is actually:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

This means that your jar file is **corrupted** for some reason, you should remove it from your local repository by deleting the folder `C:\Users\userName\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\txw2` and relaunch your command `mvn clean install` in order to download it again.

Comment: the thing is I havent found repository txw2 having such folder structure as show in exception....

Comment: Could not load com/sun/xml/txw2/DatatypeWriter.class.

Comment: try with a more recent version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.txw2/txw2